# Como carregar imagens após scroll quando estiverem no view-port?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Observem essa página:

https://www.nubank.com.br/gerando-boletos/

Ela tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
<p>titulo do post</p>
<img src>

<p>titulo do post</p>
<img src>

<p>titulo do post</p>
<img src>
```

Mas o que estou querendo saber é como fazer o efeito de aparecer aos poucos que ocorre nas imagens APENAS quando rolamos a página e então chegamos na imagem.

Devo pesquisar por oque?

Segundo a resposta de um colega abaixo, tentei da forma abaixo e não funcionou.

A figura apenas aparece. Confirmei a lnkagem dos arquivos

```
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js"></script>


<p>Titulo.</p>
<img class="lazy" src="payment_swipe.png">

<script>
  $(function() {

      $("img.lazy").lazyload({
         effect : "fadeIn"
      })


  });
</script>
```

Comment: O atributo `src` você substitui por `data-original` na imagem.

Comment: <img class="lazy" data-original="payment_swipe.png">, a imagem apareceu normalmente mas o efeito não ocorreu

Comment: Acho que consegui, peguei as ultimas versões do JQuery e do Plugin e deu certo. Só que o fadein está ocorrendo rápido demais. Tem como diminui essa velocidade?

Comment: só adicionar `effectspeed: 900 ` nos parâmetros do método...

Comment: E ai, deu certo?

Comment: sim, deu sim. Obrigado. Também encontrei o ScrollReveal que também é muito bom. Depois olha lá. https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ou você utiliza algum Javascript desenvolvido para fazer esse efeito ou você utiliza algum plugin pronto, sugiro o [Lazy Load](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- jQuery necessário -->
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js"></script>

<p>titulo do post</p>
<img class="lazy"  data-original="img/example.jpg">

<p>titulo do post</p>
<img class="lazy"  data-original="img/example.jpg">

<p>titulo do post</p>
<img class="lazy"  data-original="img/example.jpg">

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("img.lazy").lazyload();
    });
</script>
```

Em geral esse é o mais utilizado, você pode posteriormente customizar os efeitos e tudo mais, ai vai da sua necessidade e disponibilidade.

Comment: Então, tentei dessa forma mas não funcionou. Poderia colocar alguma coisa on-line desse tipo fazendo favor? Coloquei na pergunta como tentei. Talvez tenha feito errado!